# Rails 5.1 Controller Action Instance variables not appearing in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is pretty weird, I must just be missing something because I've done this a million times, and this is the first time I am seeing this.

Vanilla create controller action:

```
  def create
    @album = Album.new(album_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @album.save
        format.html { redirect_to @album, notice: 'Album was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @album }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @album.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def album_params
    params.require(:album).permit(:title)
  end
```

And a vanilla view after a successful create of an Album:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @album.title %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_album_path(@album) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', albums_path %>
```

I checked through debugging that after I create the album, @album is correctly set up. I also set a second instance variable @foo = 100. But in any event when the view gets rendered, both instance variables are nil, and I get this error (see image, it was the easiest way)

[image]

Comment: Show your controller show action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the request parameters section, you will see:

```
{ "controller" => "albums", "action" => "show", "id" => "20" }
```

The error is coming from rendering the `show` action, not the `create` action.

What is happening is that after you create the `@album`, it is doing a `redirect_to` the `show` action.

That `show` action is likely not defined and is not setting up the `@album` instance variable

Comment: thanks for the friendly (see above) response to a dumb mistake :)